# Failing to pip install Tensorflow into Atom/Hydrogen

Tags: python, tensorflow, atom-editor, hydrogen

I have been bouncing around Internet tutorials on the above for 2 days now... but since I don't know what I don't know... I'm really stuck.

**Objective :** Start using Keras/tensorflow on Atom via Hydrogen that I have started using (and find complexe but great)
Problem : I get this when I try to run a script :

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <module>
      1 import sys
----> 2 import tensorflow as tf
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

So normaly I would pip install Tensorflow as per instructions:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip
However, I get :

```
2022-06-04 13:23:02.085667: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
```

and some other dll not found (CUDA and other SW are installed as per above instructions)
And still do not resolve the initial problem. This probably stems from my misunderstandings of PIP, virtual environments, PATH variables MiniConda tutti quanti.

**Question :** Why, after installing Tensorflow via PIP do I still get the error that Tensorflow is not installed ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you installing TensorFlow into the same environment as the ipykernel you're using with Hydrogen? Apart from that, which step in the TensorFlow installation instructions gives you that warning? And what's the other error exactly? Please provide the [exact error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341).

Comment: Thanks for taking your time for me. I have upgraded to Python 3.10 now and it seems to have been taken into account by Atom. The installation of Tensorflow seems to work fine. It's only when I load a script calling in Tensorflow that I get the following messaqge from Atom : Python 3 (ipykernel)

2022-07-07 14:56:31.496944: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found 2022-07-07 14:56:31.497130: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29]